# get data from clicked div in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4

hi i have this set of div for looped which contains data from the database here is how it looks like
[image]

here is my code to generate these divs

```
@foreach($NSAdata as $list)
        {{ Session::put('isList' , 'true')}}
        <div class="divcont">
            <p>Filename : {{$list->filename}}</p>
            <span>Size     : {{$list->filesize}}</span>
            @if($list->filetype == 'ppt' || $list->filetype == 'pptx')
                <img src="{{ asset('img/ico/pptico.PNG') }}" class="imgicoII">

            @elseif($list->filetype == 'doc' || $list->filetype == 'docx')
                <img src="{{ asset('img/ico/wordico.PNG') }}" class="imgicoII">

            @elseif($list->filetype == 'pdf')
                <img src="{{ asset('img/ico/pdfico.PNG') }}" class="imgicoII">

            @elseif($list->filetype == 'xls' || $list->filetype == 'xlsx')
                <img src="{{ asset('img/ico/excelico.PNG') }}" class="imgicoII">

             @elseif($list->filetype == 'txt')
                <img src="{{ asset('img/ico/txtico.png') }}" class="imgicoII">

            @elseif($list->filetype == 'csv')
                <img src="{{ asset('img/ico/csvico.PNG') }}" class="imgicoII">
            @endif
            <br>
            @if($list->thumbnail != 'n/a')
                <img src="{{ asset('uploads/docs/thumb/' . $list->thumbnail ) }}" class="imgicoIII">
            @else
                <img src="{{ asset('uploads/docs/thumb/noThumb.png' ) }}" class="imgicoIII">
            @endif
            <br>
            <a class="modal-trigger z-depth-1 btn dgray " href="#modFile">
                Edit
            </a>
            <a href="{{URL::route('openfile', array($list->fileid))}}" class="btn dgray">
                View
            </a>
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

when the user clicked the edit button i trigger a modal with an id of `modFile`, it is supposed to display a modal where it contains the data from the clicked div im able to display the modal but im not displaying the correct data. here is my code for the modal

```
<div id="modFile" class="modal modal1size">
<div id="modal-header" class="z-depth-2 blue lighten-1">
</div>
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="row rowMarg">
        <h6>Information.</h6>

            @if(Session::has('isList'))
                <h6>Filename    : {{ $list->filename }}  </h6>
                <h6>File type   : {{ $list->filetype }} </h6>
                <?php $extension = "";?>
                @if($extension == 'ppt' || $extension == 'pptx')
                    <img src="{{ asset('img/ico/pptico.PNG') }}" class="imgico">
                @elseif($extension == 'doc' || $extension == 'docx')
                    <img src="{{ asset('img/ico/wordico.PNG') }}" class="imgico">
                @endif

                <h6>Size        : {{ $list->filesize }} </h6>

                <br>

            @endif
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer grey lighten-4">
    <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-darkblue-1 btn-flat buttoninset">Submit</button>
    <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-darkblue-1 btn-flat buttoninset">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

the thing is it just display wrong info any idea what i am doing wrong or how can i improve my code?

Comment: for improving your code please upgrade immediately to laravel 5.2

Comment: your edit button has no link and item ID `<a class="modal-trigger z-depth-1 btn dgray " href="#modFile">
                Edit
            </a>`

Comment: hi @Iftikharuddin any ideas on how to get the item id of the div?

Comment: as you did in view do it same in Edit change the `href='#modfile' to {{URL::route('EditFile', array($list->fileid))}}`

Comment: hi @Iftikharuddin the page where the divs are generated and the modal are of the same page only